# Python line not running

Tags: python

```
while True:
  inp = raw_input()
  if inp == "":pres= input("What would you like to know about me? AGE, JOKE, FACT")
if pres in {'AGE'}:
  print("I was birthed from my mother 87 years ago.")
if pres in {'JOKE'}:
   print("Where do polar bears keep their money?")
   import time
   time.sleep(2)
   print("In a snow bank!")
if pres in {"FACT"}:
  print("Hippopotamus's have pink spit!")
```

I am a student and for my school project have to do a code and for some reason I can't figure out how to get the chatbot to answer the question when someone puts in AGE, JOKE or FACT. Insteas, it just repeats the question when I press enter.

Comment: you need to come out of while loop in order not to repeat same thing

Comment: Please check your indentation.

Comment: props to olivia for being 87 years old and just now getting into coding!

Comment: that is an inside joke I am actually fifteen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for input in your `while True` loop. It will never exit, because `True` is... always true. You need to put the `if` statements inside the loop for them to execute as well.

Comment: I get it now, thank you!